# Cases when binding are detached automatically

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

Today I faced a problem which reminded me of bindings being detached automatically in some cases. I am not sure but here is the scenario -

I attach a menu item bound to a property(implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`), like this -

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayLongUnit, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Now in its checked event handler I update its `IsChecked` value after checking some condition like this -

```
If( condition == true){menuItem.IsChecked = true}
```

Now will the binding be still attached or it will get lost? (I remember reading somewhere that it will be lost).

**Are there any scenarios in which bindings will be detached automatically?**

One I could find out is mentioned here -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/08d6e4c4-47ab-44f3-b19a-c0ab872fb1a8

Answer (score 8):

About knowing whether a binding has been detached: what you can do is debug your binding.
First you add the diagnostics namespace in your XAML. Here's an example on a Window (I've removed the other usual namespaces for clarity):

```
<Window xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase">
```

then you enable trace on a binding. Here's an example with a binding set on a TextBox's Text property:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding FirstName, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High} />
```

Now if you look in the Output tab of Visual Studio when running your program, you'll see informations about your binding, including "**detach**" when it's been detached.

So this doesn't tell you WHY it was detached, only when.
It can help though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a two-way binding?

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayLongUnit, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A more specific example of what your problem is is here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4165daed-2eaf-450b-a082-63d79ff9fd3e

You might want to make the binding mode two way (that way your property will be updated too, and I don't know what the default is for IsChecked, but it's always best to be explicit) or simply change the DisplayLongUnit property in stead of the IsChecked property.

Comment: Thanks for your response Carrotman but I am not facing any issue with the binding example I provided in my question. The question is about binding getting reset or lost in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set "IsCheckable" to true. If it's false, the TwoWay binding won't work. The following data-bound MenuItem works for me (no code-behind):

```
<MenuItem Header="Select sense" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableSenses}" >
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Sense.English}" />
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```